# Does groovy "cast" a string to an integer based on its hashCode/ASCII Code?

Tags: string, groovy, casting, integer

I started coding with `groovy` today and I notices that if I take the following code:

```
int aaa = "6"
log.info(aaa)
```

The output I get is:

```
54 <-- (ASCII Code for '6')
```

If I assign `aaa` with any number which is beyond the range of `0..9` I get a class cast exception.
Looks like if the string is actually a single `character` - `groovy` converts its `ASCII` code/`hashCode`.

I tried this code:

```
int aaa = "A"
log.info(aaa)
```

And the output I got was:

```
65 <-- (ASCII code for 'A')
```

What is the official reason for this? 
Is it because `groovy` automatically changes `"A"` into `'A'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jochen [says here in the JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-1211?focusedCommentId=56390&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#action_56390); Strings of length 1 are converted to chars if needed (and by putting it into an int variable, it is assuming that that is what you want to do)

If you want to accept bigger numbers, you can do:

```
int a = '12345' as int
```

And that will convert the whole number to an int.